# If statement that builds a full result

Tags: jquery

Im working on this project where there are 8 select options. If the user selects options under this one select area it populates and builds a link to a store front. Everything works great, all the selects have there proper value, the link gets built. But, it doesnt go to the link (smeh). Here is my jQuery code. Im pretty sure its somewhere in the way I modeled it.

```
$('#tf-bundles input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    if ($('#tf-key-sel .quantity').val() == "0" && $('#tf-key-sel .padType').val == "0") {

    } else {
        tfkeyboardqua = $('#tf-key-sel .quantity').val();
        tfkeyboardpad = $('#tf-key-sel .padType').val();
        keyboardcombine = 'ProductCode=' + tfkeyboardpad + '&Qty.' + tfkeyboardpad + '=' + tfkeyboardqua;
    };
    if ($('#tf-case-sel .quantity').val() == "0" && $('#tf-case-sel .padType').val == "0" && $('#tf-case-sel .padColor').val == "0") {

    } else {
        tfcasesqua = $('#tf-case-sel .quantity').val();
        tfcasescolor = $('#tf-case-sel .padColor').val();
        tfcasespad = $('#tf-case-sel .padType').val();
        casecombine = 'ProductCode=' + tfcasespad + '-' + tfcasescolor + '&Qty.' + tfcasespad + '=' + tfcasesqua;
    };
    if ($('#tf-case-sel .quantity').val() == "0" && $('#tf-case-sel .padType').val == "0" && $('#tf-case-sel .padColor').val == "0") {

    } else {
        tfcomboqua = $('#tf-key-case-sel .quantity').val();
        tfcombopad = $('#tf-key-case-sel .padColor').val();
        tfcombocolor = $('#tf-key-case-sel .padType').val();
        combocombine = 'ProductCode=' + tfkeyboardpad + '-' + tfcombocolor + '&Qty.' + tfkeyboardpad + '=' + tfkeyboardqua;
    };
    if (keyboardcombine != "" && casecombine == "" && combocombine == "") {
        window.location.href = solidLink + keyboardcombine;
    }
});
```

Here is one set of HTML

```
<ul class="selection">
    <li>
        Quantity
        <select class="quantity">
            <option value="0">How Many</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="question">
        <img src="images/circle-q.png" alt="q" class="question ">Select Your iPad
        <select class="padType">
            <option value="0">Choose your iPad</option>
            <option value="TF-8483-BK">iPad 1</option>
            <option value="TF-8483-BK">iPad 2</option>
            <option value="TF-8483-BK">iPad 3</option>
            <option value="TF-8483-BK">iPad 4</option>
            <option value="TF-2731-BK">iPad mini</option>
            <option value="TF-2772-BK">iPad Air</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        Select Color
        <select class="padColor">
            <option value="0">Choose your color</option>
            <option value="BK">Black</option>
            <option value="BL">Blue</option>
            <option value="GY">Light Grey</option>
            <option value="RD">Red</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The part of my jQuery that I believe is the issue is this below :

```
if (keyboardcombine != "" && casecombine == "" && combocombine == "") {
    window.location.href = solidLink+keyboardcombine;
}
```

Comment: Your final condition says "if `keyboardcombine` is not an empty string, and `casecombine` and `combocombine` both are empty strings, then redirect the window", and I only see one spot where that would be true which is around line 7, and this is assuming you've set `casecombine` and `combocombine` to empty strings somewhere before this code. I also noticed you used a few `$(...).val == ...`, which should be `$(...).val() == ...`. I would suggest using Chrome debug tools (`console.log` and friends) to spit out the expected values in your final condition and work backward from there.

Comment: Are you sure the code actually goes inside of the if statement near the end?

Comment: So have the last of statement run once it had a value